# Stackdriver Error Reporting - Custom Data - NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

Currently trying to use Stackdriver Error Reporting with .NET Core 2.1, works great, but now, I had like to append custom label/field/data to a request.

Using the official lib `Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the [method](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report) the api is calling does not have room for custom labels. Please log a feature request [here](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report). And for the benefit of the community, you can also update the link here for tracking purposes.